# Python: Replacing a newline with a space between multiline comments

Tags: python, regex

I am relatively new to python and i need to print the multiline comments used in the C program.
I have a test.c file which is as below:

```
/* print multiline

   comments */
```

I tried the following python code to parse the C code and print the multiline comments

```
import re 

fileopen = open('test.c', 'rw')

for var in fileopen:
    if var.startswith("/*"):
        var1 = re.sub(r'\n', " ", var)
        var1 = var.rstrip()
        print var1
```

The output I get is:

```
/* print multiline
```

The second line of the comment does not get printed even if I substitute newline with a space.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: It's a _bad_ idea to make use of regex in such cases.

Comment: The problem is you're reading one line at a time.  As others said you have to be careful when parsing code...

Answer (score 2):

If your only requirement is finding comments that span multiple lines, thats actually quite easy. Like so:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"\/\*(.*\n.*)\*\/", code, re.MULTILINE):
    print match.group(1)
```

The important part is:

```
\/\*(.*\n.*)\*\/
```

Which finds a literal `/*`, any number of characters, a newline, any number of characters and a literal `*/`, and captures the parts between the comment delimiters.

Additionally, the flag [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) allows the regex search to search across lines, which allows us to enforce that it *must* be a multiline comment.

The [full code can be run on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/NscedCDT):

```
code= """/* print multiline
   comments */

// One line comment
/* Another one line comment */

/* Multiline
   comment */
"""

import re

for match in re.finditer(r"\/\*(.*\n.*)\*\/", code, re.MULTILINE):
    print match.group(1)
```

Which gives:

```
print multiline
  comments 
Multiline
  comment
```

Comment: Without [\n]* the regex would not return comments which just have one line. The regex should be "\/\*(.*[\n]*.*)\*\/

Comment: @GuruDevanla Well, the OP asked for "multiline" comments, so this returns multiline comments.

Comment: Fair enough, its up to the OP to decide what he wants.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**

It was pointed out that the pre-processor phase likely takes care of comments, and upon further reflection, I concur. A full parser would not be necessary.

**Original (ignore):**

Really to properly implement this you would need to implement a parser for a C grammar at least as far as comments go, since there is a wide variety of syntaxes that would qualify as valid C comments that a standard regex would not capture.

For example, here's a link to a C grammar in a Yacc file: http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html.

Note that a comment isn't even an individual component -- it's actually a sub-component, where a the slash is a separate production.

Comment: I think you do not need the full grammar for this task.  Just a tokenizer.

Comment: I stand corrected. You are correct that the pre-processor handles the comments: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor. Still, a regex really isn't the tool to use here.

Comment: Why not? Using across line searching this is a trivial case for a regex as shown by my answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't a regex work? Or a simple hand-written parser? What are the complex cases?